# yii2 url rewrite config

Tags: apache, yii

i'm a newbie of yii2, i've follow the instruction to install the yii2 by composer, but stuck in the url rewrite config on ubuntu server.

my apache2 config file as following:

```
Alias /math2 /usr/share/math2/frontend/web
Alias /admin /usr/share/math2/backend/web

<Directory "/usr/local/math2/frontend/web">
    RewriteEngine On
    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteBase /math2
    #RewriteRule . index.php
    RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L]
</Directory>

<Directory "/usr/local/math2/backend/web">
    # if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # otherwise forward it to index.php
    RewriteBase /admin
    RewriteRule . index.php
</Directory>
```

and the yii config file as following:

```
<?php
return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'urlManager' => [
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false
        ],
    ],
];
```

My VirtualHost as following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

i can visit the site normally by http://localhost/math2/index.php/site/about

but it is suppose to be visited by
http://localhost/math2/site/about
which i get a 404 error now.

Comment: Is it Apache 404 or Yii 404 error? This is very important. If it's apache 404, than it's apache misconfiguration.

Comment: seems like you need to configure apache virtual hosts for this to work. see http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/47615-yii-20-basci-app-i-miss-the-htaccess-file/

Comment: still not work~ sth wrong with my apache config~

Answer (score 1):

I actually do not use aliases with virtual hosts to get similar urls. I have in project root .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
Options FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/$
RewriteRule ^(admin)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin
RewriteRule ^admin(/.+)?$ /backend/web/$1 [L,PT]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /frontend/web/$1
```

In frontend/web and backend/web i have .htaccess like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```