# controllermap in yii2 return 404

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I walk around yii2 manual by copy this code in [manual](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#controllerMap)

```
    'controllerMap' => [
        'account' => 'yii\app\controllers\UserController',
        'article' => [
            'class' => 'yii\app\controllers\PostController',
            'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
        ],
],
```

paste in netbean

[image]

just access it

[image]

already have UserController
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your namespace is wrong! If you look at documentation, the correct code is like this:

```
[
    'controllerMap' => [
        'account' => 'app\controllers\UserController',
        'article' => [
            'class' => 'app\controllers\PostController',
            'enableCsrfValidation' => false,
        ],
    ],
]
```

But you have an extra `yii` in the beginning of the namespace, so `yii\app\controllers\UserController` must be `app\controllers\UserController`.

Also i think you have some problems in url rewriting. If I'm true, you can find an instrument for fixing it in http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#using-pretty-urls and [yii2 url rewrite config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28407055/yii2-url-rewrite-config).